# looking to receive calls made to a twilio US phone number (I'm abroad)

Tags: twilio

I'm working for a US Client and integrating Twilio on their platform.
The app will make phone calls to employees, using text-to-speach to communicate a message and wait for a response (press 1, or press 2, ...).

I live in Colombia so i have no proper way to test it, i am looking for an app for my phone or computer that will allow me to attach a twilio US phone number i own, so i can receive the calls from another phone number i own.

Have been looking around with no success.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to register a SIP end-point directly to Twilio, to make and receive calls.

[Registering a SIP Phone Directly to Twilio (and so much more...)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound)

There are some mobile friendly SIP clients as well you could use with the blog above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have read the article, but don't understand how all this works